# App Intent Problem | Your app contains an Intent Redirection vulnerability

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, security, android-intent

I got this message after updating app in play console. I am sharing code of a method where the error is, as suggested by Google. I never updated this part of the code and it never showed any problem before. I am not sure why it is showing me an error. Do I need to update the way of saving a file? I hope to find a solution here.

```
       public void saveDocument(ScannedDocument scannedDocument) {

        Mat doc = (scannedDocument.processed != null) ? scannedDocument.processed : scannedDocument.original;

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String fileName;
        boolean isIntent = false;
        Uri fileUri = null;

        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE")) {
            fileUri = ((Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT));
            Log.d(TAG, "intent uri: " + fileUri.toString());
            try {
                fileName = File.createTempFile("onsFile", ".jpg", this.getCacheDir()).getPath();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }
            isIntent = true;
        } else {
            String folderName = mSharedPref.getString("storage_folder", FOLDER_NAME);
            File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).toString()
                    + "/" + folderName);
            if (!folder.exists()) {
                folder.mkdirs();
                Log.d(TAG, "wrote: created folder " + folder.getPath());
            }
            fileName = folder.getAbsolutePath()
                    + "/DOC-"
                    + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss").format(new Date())
                    + ".jpg";
        }

        Mat endDoc = new Mat(Double.valueOf(doc.size().width).intValue(),
                Double.valueOf(doc.size().height).intValue(), CvType.CV_8UC4);

        Core.flip(doc.t(), endDoc, 1);

        Imgcodecs.imwrite(fileName, endDoc);
        endDoc.release();

        try {
            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(fileName);
            exif.setAttribute("UserComment", "Generated");
            String nowFormatted = mDateFormat.format(new Date().getTime());
            exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME, nowFormatted);
            exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME_DIGITIZED, nowFormatted);
          //  exif.setAttribute("Software", "OpenNoteScanner " + BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME + "");
            exif.saveAttributes();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (isIntent) {
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            OutputStream realOutputStream = null;
            try {
                inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
                realOutputStream = this.getContentResolver().openOutputStream(fileUri);
                // Transfer bytes from in to out
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int len;
                while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    realOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, len);
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            } finally {
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                    realOutputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }

        animateDocument(fileName, scannedDocument);

        Log.d(TAG, "wrote: " + fileName);

        if (isIntent) {
            new File(fileName).delete();
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
        } else {
            addImageToGallery(fileName, this);
        }

        refreshCamera();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Google has a page on [Mitigating Intent Redirection vulnerabilities](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/9267555?hl=en) that you should read carefully.

The short version is that the vulnerability could potentially<sup>1</sup> be exploited by a malicious app to allow it to access private app components or files.

The document explains three possible ways to mitigate this vulnerability.  Unfortunately, there is not enough context to be sure which of the three is most appropriate for your app.  However, the first one is straightforward:

> *"If the affected app component does not need to receive Intents from other apps then you can make that app component private by setting `android:exported="false" in your Manifest."*

---

> I never updated this part of the code and it never showed any problem before.

That could mean that this is a relatively new kind of Android vulnerability, or that Google's methodology for detecting it has become more rigorous since last time you published your app.

> Do I need to update the way of saving a file?

Possibly yes.  Or possibly one of the mitigations will be sufficient.

> I hope to find a solution here.

There are some possible solutions in the Google document I linked to.

---

<sup>1 - It is moot if it is *actually* possible to exploit the vulnerability in your app.  The point is that Google Play Store's scanning / analysis / testing methodology has found what *they believe to be a problem*.  Their goal is to protect Play Store users.</sup>